# Subir Aplicativo na Windows Store

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Tenho um `aplicativo universal` criado no `visual studio 2015` atualizado. Ao subir a aplicação e apresentada seguinte mensagem :

**Erro** :

> "A dependência de pacote declarada não existe. Dependência:
>   Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0. Versão mínima: 1.0.23430.0. Carregue o
>   arquivo .appxupload gerado pelo Visual Studio para a Loja."

Imagem do erro:

[image: imagem do erro]

Comment: Jovem, coloque o texto do erro, não uma imagem. Muitos de nós não conseguem visualizar imagens por causa de bloqueios.